# Auto black list hackers from Apache server that hit website too fast

Tags: hacking, apache-2.4, webfilter

I notice some hackers jumping from website to website iterating all possible IP addresses and hitting them so fast and hard with their attack URLs to get some flaws. I am more interested in how to automatically block their IP addresses using Apache server as soon as they hit certain limit (eg. too big data, too frequent). At the moment we waste outgoing traffic by returning them error page. I know their requests are not legitimate since I am not running PHP server and they keep making such requests.

I hope someone can help me with Apache configuration so the server can reduce the outgoing traffic of returning unnecessary error page.

Comment: For many people a solution like [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org) works adequately or [mod security](https://www.modsecurity.org/) is put to good use. For most of us that is the normal background noise that comes with running public online services...

Comment: The other resolution would of course be to simply reduce size of your error pages. Since most bots would only notice the error code and not parse any HTML, a page consisting of an `img` tag with the screenshot of your current error page should work miracles...

Comment: these are not hackers, just a dumb bots, start from here: http://pastebin.com/5Hw9KZnW